# Manipulate List of List

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

In my script I am Trying to fetch records from DB as List of lists

```
KEYWORD Collections . Log List ${query_results}
Documentation:  
Logs the length and contents of the list using given level.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20180306 20:49:59.894 / 20180306 20:49:59.894 / 00:00:00.000
20:49:59.894    INFO    List length is 20 and it contains following items:
0: ('3/6/2018', 6, 3, '  50.00', 984, 286, 29.07)
1: ('3/5/2018', 6, 4, '  66.67', 984, 866, 88.01)
2: ('3/4/2018', 6, 4, '  66.67', 984, 976, 99.19)
3: ('3/3/2018', 6, 4, '  66.67', 984, 884, 89.84)
4: ('3/2/2018', 6, 4, '  66.67', 984, 864, 87.8)
5: ('3/1/2018', 7, 5, '  71.43', 1848, 1440, 77.92)
6: ('2/28/2018', 6, 4, '  66.67', 1656, 1248, 75.36)
7: ('2/27/2018', 6, 4, '  66.67', 1656, 1248, 75.36)
8: ('2/26/2018', 6, 1, '  16.67', 1656, 1248, 75.36)
9: ('2/25/2018', 6, 1, '  16.67', 1656, 1056, 63.77)
10: ('2/24/2018', 8, None, None, 816, 80, 9.8)
11: ('2/23/2018', 11, 3, '  27.27', 1464, 128, 8.74)
12: ('2/22/2018', 11, 7, '  63.64', 2232, 1292, 57.89)
13: ('2/21/2018', 11, 2, '  18.18', 2232, 1239, 55.51)
14: ('2/20/2018', 11, None, None, 2232, 184, 8.24)
15: ('2/19/2018', 6, None, None, 1752, 0, 0)
16: ('2/18/2018', 6, None, None, 528, 0, 0)
17: ('2/17/2018', 6, None, None, 528, 0, 0)
18: ('2/16/2018', 7, None, None, 1680, 0, 0)
19: ('2/15/2018', 6, 2, '  33.33', 1584, 93, 5.87)
```

As you can see some data is coming as None(They are NULL values from DB).I want to replace such data into 0.00. I am not sure how to do this in Robot Framework. Can some one help me achieving this?

Comment: Is there any reason why this can not be done at the DB level in the SQL query?

Comment: When I checked with Dev they are handling this at code level. did n't thought we can handle from DB Level. Good Idea, Let me give a try. Thanks @A.Kootstra

Comment: Yes, I am able to using nvl(to_char(mycolumn), '0')  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to A.kootstra for his idea.

Instead of handling this problem at Robot Framework level, I am able to handle this using Oracle function with in SQL Query.

```
i.e.  nvl(to_char(mycolumn), '0')  This Replaces NULL to desired value
```